Не отправляются письма через SMTP
Поднял свой SMTP-сервер по докам. Письма через браузер отправляются. Решил написать скрипт на Python для отправки писем, которые в очереди стоят:
def send_email(email_from, message):
    sender_email = 'MY_USER_1@MYDOMAIN.ru'
    sender_password = "MY_FAKE_PASS"

    session = smtplib.SMTP('mail.MYDOMAIN.ru', MY_PORT_SMTP)
    try:
        session.starttls()
        session.login(sender_email, sender_password)
        session.sendmail(sender_email, email_from, message)
    finally:
        session.quit()

email_from = "MY_USER_2@MYDOMAIN.ru"
body = "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; bou.......4557==--"

send_email(email_from, body)

MY_PORT_SMTP - взял из админки почтовика
Падает с ошибкой:

raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

Сама функция отправки письма рабочая, т.к. если указать параметры почты yandex, то отправка пройдет успешно.
Куда мне копать?

